# Django - Running a mysql restore via python

Tags: mysql, django

I have a Django project that I'm working on that has a lot of tables and data. We're still in dev mode, so we're doing a lot of testing. I'd like to be able to give a few users access to the project now so as to play with it with fake data. I took the time to set up all the fake data so that when they open the web-app, it's already populated with records that are in various states - as they might find the system when its in production.

My goal is to allow them to play around with everything, but then have a big "Reset" button that they can hit which will bring the whole thing back to square one - so to speak. Basically, it will put all the records and data back to the way it was when I handed it over to them with data. This way, they can muck around, test things, and then start over and do more testing.

*Edit - I should say it's only one tester so resetting doesn't affect anyone else*

I made a quick view in Django that runs a mysql restore command, but it is hanging. My view looks like this:

```
def reset_db(request):
  reset = "mysql -v -u garfonzo -pMyPassword dbName < db_reset.sql"
  os.system(reset)
  return HttpResponse("success?")
```

All it is supposed to do is restore the DB to its original state. However, it hangs. With the `-v` command, I see that the last thing it does is this:

```
...a whole bunch of MySQL queries.... then
--------------
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `auth_permission` ENABLE KEYS */
--------------

--------------
UNLOCK TABLES
--------------

--------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `auth_user`
--------------
```

It just sits here... doing nothing, then my web-app is unresponsive. I have to kill the process and start over (resetting manually).

I suppose my question is twofold:

1. Is this the best way to achieve a reset button for users? If not, what's a better way?
2. If this is the best way to achieve this, why would the code hang?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the reset script have any data? How much? What happens if you do the same without `-v` option?

Comment: The reset variable (everything in the quotes) is just a normal command line command so there is no data. It's just calling on `mysql` to do load the file `db_reset.sql` into the database `dbName`. Taking out the `-v` has the same effect (hangs). I put it in there to see if I could get any clues as to what was happening.

Comment: I mean if the sql file `db_reset.sql` has any data.

Comment: Oh, it has the output of doing `mysqldump -u garfonzo -pMyPassword dbName > db_resent.sql` So it's a mysql dump file with all the data to recreate the database. I can run the `reset` command normally from the command line without any hangs or problems.

Comment: If the importing is taking long time, it's possible that it's freezing the app. Instead of executing the command via the python script itself, try using something like [Fabric](http://fabfile.org).

Comment: Interesting thought, however, when I run it from the command line, it's quick (there isn't *that* much data) - maybe 3 seconds or so? Would that be enough to freeze the app?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24779/discussion-between-garfonzo-and-bibhas)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to provide fixtures for all your initial data and provide the user with a view to run syncdb which will reset everything again with your initial data. However I havent tried this myself.

```
from django.core.management import call_command

def reset_db(request):
     call_command('syncdb', interactive=False)
```

Comment: But I don't want the inital data to be there forever - this is just a temporary testing stage. Once things are working properly, I will provide an empty web-app. Seems to me that adding initial data would take a lot of programming and extra work for a small result.

Comment: @Garfonzo it is not effort at all, use  manage.py dumpdata and put its output in myapp/fixtures/initial_data.json. then every time you run syncdb it will load everything again for you. No programming at all. and once testing is done, get rid of this file :)

Comment: Oh, I was imagining entering code into each model/class. That sounds great, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is the command I use to restore my database. Make sure you are on the unix terminal.
mysql -u(username) -p(password) (name of database)